# How common is the side-effect of "outbursts of words/sounds" for one taking Dexedrine for ADD?

Tags: medications, side-effects, adhd, behavior, speech

A few years ago, I was diagnosed with adult ADD. Initially, I was prescribed with Adderall when I lived in the USA, but when I moved to Canada, my doctors switched me to Dexedrine for whatever reason (I think costs?).

Around the same time I started taking Dexedrine (about 4 years ago), I developed a quirk where I randomly blurt out words (such as names of my family members) or make little yelps for no reason whatsoever -- even when I was alone. I thought I was just an odd person. My family noticed it too when I visited them, and they playfully make fun of me. And I never understood why it is that I do this because I don't consciously make the decision to do these things. It's not a big deal, and it's not harming my life in any capacity, it's just odd... especially since I'm such a serious person.

Then one day I was reading the fine print of the side-effects of Dexedrine (to see if it could be causing other symptoms in my life), and I noticed that it says: **"outbursts of words/sounds"** on  http://www.webmd.com/drugs/2/drug-89051/dexedrine-spansule-oral/details#side-effects.

**What does that mean exactly? Does that explain my quirky behavior? Is their a medical definition for this type of behavior? Is it like turrets of the mouth? How common of a side-effect is it in patients that take Dexedrine for ADD?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: it says on the WebMD link you posted that you should consult your doctor immediately if you experience the side effect of "outbursts of words/sounds." Please be sure you do so.

The word for the involuntary behaviors you're experiencing is [tics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic). They are "verbal tics" if you are saying words, or "vocal tics" if you are making non-word sounds with your voice. Some people group both these into "phonic tics," since you use your vocal cords to make sounds with both.

You also ask about [Tourette Syndrome](http://www.ninds.nih.gov/disorders/tourette/detail_tourette.htm). Verbal and vocal tics are a characteristic of this syndrome. Having the tics does not mean you have Tourette Syndrome. Consult your physician about this as well.